# How to get the index of what is clicked inside the div.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

> The HTML file has a video player using  and  that shows the images. The Js file has an array of image and videos. I have to play a particular video on a particular image click. when image[0] is clicked video[0] should play and likewise. I have added a click event to all the images inside this div. how to identify index of image that was clicked by the person so what I can assign the URL (source)of the video at that same index in video array to the src of my main video player. I have made some code here

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
 .leftElement {
float: left;
  }

  .rightElement {
float: right;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
 <body>

  <div class="blocks">

            <div id="showThumbnailDiv" style="height: 250px; width: 480px;
               overflow:scroll; margin-top: 7%; margin-left: 8%;" class="scroll  
               leftElement">    
                       <script src="showdynamicimages.js"></script>
            </div>

            <div id="videoplayer" class="rightElement" style="margin-top: 7%; 
                 margin-right: 8%;">

                     <video id="mainVideo" width="480" height="250" autoplay controls> 
                     </video>
            </div>

    </div>

   <div>position_click</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Js File is

```
                    var position_click;
                    var image =[



    "http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/624_351/images/live/p0/1p/5y/p01p5ygs.jpg",
    "http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg",
     "http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/52cddfb169beddee2a6c2246/the-29-coolest-us-air-force-images-of-the-year.jpg", 

     "http://thatrandomwebsite.com/uploads/3/2/8/4/3284350/7497257_orig.jpg",   
      "http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/33-most-powerful-images-23.jpeg",
     "http://blog.gettyimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/81076116-Chip-Somodevilla-Getty-Images-e1351541533518.jpg",
    "http://www.thehindu.com/multimedia/dynamic/01532/THINGSSEE_INTERNET_1532062g.jpg", 
     "http://wpmedia.o.canada.com/2014/04/gv_0402_newspicofday_0011.jpg", 
    "http://www.freelive3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images-7.jpg"];


         var videos = [
              "uploaded_videos/outro_en.mp4",
              "uploaded_videos/alu_blech_en.mp4",
              "uploaded_videos/alu_guss_en.mp4",
               "uploaded_videos/b_saeule_en.mp4",
               "uploaded_videos/intro_en.mp4"];


       for( var i=0; i<10; i++)
            {    
                 var elem = document.createElement("img");
                 elem.setAttribute("src", image[i]);
                 elem.setAttribute("height", "120");
                 elem.setAttribute("width", "150");
                 elem.setAttribute("alt", "Unable to display Image");
                 elem.setAttribute("class","thumbnail");
                 document.getElementById("showThumbnailDiv").appendChild(elem);
            }

           var image = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
           for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {

                  image[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
             }

          function clickHandler(el) {

                 var mainVideo = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
                 mainVideo.src = videos[0];
              }
```

> Please suggest how can I proceed here..???

Comment: I can't see any image in html code

Comment: Images are loading in js files @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: they are being added dynamically in the JS file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way Working Fiddle Below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var image = [
    "http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/624_351/images/live/p0/1p/5y/p01p5ygs.jpg",
    "http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg",
    "http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/52cddfb169beddee2a6c2246/the-29-coolest-us-air-force-images-of-the-year.jpg",
    "http://thatrandomwebsite.com/uploads/3/2/8/4/3284350/7497257_orig.jpg",
    "http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/33-most-powerful-images-23.jpeg",
    "http://blog.gettyimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/81076116-Chip-Somodevilla-Getty-Images-e1351541533518.jpg",
    "http://www.thehindu.com/multimedia/dynamic/01532/THINGSSEE_INTERNET_1532062g.jpg",
    "http://wpmedia.o.canada.com/2014/04/gv_0402_newspicofday_0011.jpg",
    "http://www.freelive3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images-7.jpg"];


var videos = [
    "uploaded_videos/outro_en.mp4",
    "uploaded_videos/alu_blech_en.mp4",
    "uploaded_videos/alu_guss_en.mp4",
    "uploaded_videos/b_saeule_en.mp4",
    "uploaded_videos/intro_en.mp4"];
var img_output=''
for(var i in image)
{
    img_output+='<img class="thumbnail" src="'+image[i]+'" height="120" width="150"/>';
}
$('#showThumbnailDiv').empty().append(img_output)

$(".thumbnail").click(function(index){
     $('#mainVideo').attr('src', videos[$(this).index()]);
    alert("loading video no "+videos[$(this).index()])
});});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cu6qn/)

Comment: +1 for the easy way to add elements, no more writing each attribute separately. I guess finding the index was an easy task I was missing..

Comment: Hey I was looking at the way you wrote src with a single quotation and a +, can I read about it somewhere..???

Comment: '+image[i]+' i can understand the '' you used here, but why + ..??

Comment: + is javascript concatinate operator . basically img tag requires src in doublequotes thats why refer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to write same code in jQuery.

Replace this

```
var image = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
     image[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
}

function clickHandler(el) {
       var mainVideo = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
       mainVideo.src = videos[0];
}
```

with

```
   $(".thumbnail").click(function(index){
        $('#videoplayer').attr('src', videos[index]);
    });
```

**Note** - If you don't have jquery file in your html then please include jquery library in head of your html.
Just copy paste this in

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I dont have to use the DOM ready function, rather I am calling this script (only the JS file) in my main HTML file (that is not the HTML file i posted here, that is just for testing)

Comment: @KartikA, yeah then in that is case you won't call it but make sure that this click handler code get called when images are attached to html code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would get the index of the image.

```
<Script>
$("#showThumbnailDiv img").click(function(){
var a = $(this).index();
.....you can now use this var to get the correct video...
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said, and some information lacking from your post here is an example.
Add an id to each image. On click get the target's id and use that as the idx to find the video.

Also you should update your js and use more jquery since you tagged it.
1.

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{    
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", image[i]);
elem.setAttribute("height", "120");
elem.setAttribute("width", "150");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Unable to display Image");
elem.setAttribute("class","thumbnail");
$(elem).attr("id", "idx_"+i);
document.getElementById("showThumbnailDiv").appendChild(elem);
}
```

2.

```
      function clickHandler(el) {

             var idx_id = $(el.target).attr('id');

             var mainVideo = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
             mainVideo.src = videos[idx_id.split('_')[1]];
          }
```